# How to Setup User Journey Viewer for Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

According to [Azure Active Directory B2C: Collecting Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom), I can collect logs on my custom policies but how do I view logs effectively?  I can't make sense of anything going directly into app insights.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom) note:

> The community has developed a user journey viewer to help identity developers. It is not supported by Microsoft and made available strictly as-is. It reads from your Application Insights instance and provides a well-structure view of the user journey events. You obtain the source code and deploy it in your own solution.

I believe the app referenced in this note is: [WingTipUserJourneyPlayerWebApplication](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipUserJourneyPlayerWebApplication), correct?  (I think that is the app b/c of [this readme.md](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/UserJourneyRecorder))

> A different version of the userjourney recorder, adapted to read B2C logs in Application Insights, can be found here as part of the wingtiptoys project. See article for details:

---

Assuming [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipUserJourneyPlayerWebApplication) is the correct app, how do I configure it to **read** my App Insights logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Word document that describes how to integrate a B2C policy with Azure Application Insights in order to log the user journey events that occur during execution of this policy and view these events in either the Azure Portal or [the User Journey Player application](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipUserJourneyPlayerWebApplication) can be downloaded from [Integrating a B2C policy with Azure Application Insights](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Integrating%20a%20B2C%20policy%20with%20Azure%20Application%20Insights.docx).

Comment: So I did make it as far as adding the app insights app id and key but barfed on startup about openid connect settings, FYI.  We should really turn this into its own GitHub project...  thanks for all ur help!!

Comment: Hi @spottedmahn, thank you for this good feedback, I'll update the Word document with the Open ID Connect configuration.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I am trying to get the UserJourneyPlay app going, but the details in the "Integrating a B2C policy with Azure Application Insights" doc seem to suggest that you must log in as a b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com user. Is this true, and if so how do I get such a user?

Comment: Hi @DouglasWoods You can ignore that. :) You must log into the User Journey Player application using credentials in your own tenant.