# How to get the User Journey Viewer for Azure AD B2C up and running?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

The [Microsoft Docs for collecting AAD B2C logs with App Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights) describe how to collect logs from custom policies. However the resulting logs are rather cryptical and very hard to interpret. Therefore the Microsoft Docs mention the [User Journey Viewer](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipUserJourneyPlayerWebApplication) developed by the community, which should provide the App Insights data as well-structured view of the user journey events. Further there is a [Word document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Integrating%20a%20B2C%20policy%20with%20Azure%20Application%20Insights.docx) which describes how to setup the User Journey Viewer-application.

Unfortunately I can not make the User Journey Player application working for my tenant. I managed to configure the App Insights-configuration but I am still missing the description for the Open ID Connect-configuration mentioned in the related [Stackoverflow-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327673/how-to-setup-user-journey-viewer-for-azure-ad-b2c/63921443#63921443). So it's obvious to replace the TenantId by using my own tenant but I am wondering which ClientId, ClientSecret, and RedirectUri I have to use to make the app working?

Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S.: Is there any documentation about how to interpret the raw data about the User Journey events in App Insights?

Comment: The Visual Studio code extension for B2C can help a bit: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureADB2CTools.aadb2c. At least it groups the data a bit and highlights ones with errors. Still you do need to understand the JSON a little bit to know what it is telling you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the VS Code B2C extension. But the main question is where can I get information about how to read the JSON?

Comment: If you find a source that helps with that, I'd be interested in that as well. I've mostly learned to read some parts of the JSON just through trial and error. It gives you quite a large amount of info, like what claim values were at different steps, did it skip a step etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess about client id, secret and redirecturi: (non b2c) application id and secret created in the B2C tenant. Redirecturi should be User Journey Player application url.